# What does the probability mass function function look like for this parametric distribution?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, recreational-mathematics

Let the parameter $\gamma$ be in $(0, 1)$ and $I_1, I_2, \dots$ a random sequence of uniformly and independently chosen closed subintervals of $[0, 1]$ of length $\gamma$ apiece. Let $X_{\gamma}$ be the minimum $n$ such that
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$$
has Lebesgue measure 1, and $Y_{\gamma}$ the minimum $n$ such that
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n I_k$$
has Lebesgue measure 0.

What is the joint probability mass function of $X_{\gamma}$ and $Y_{\gamma}$?

**Thoughts**

1. $f_{\gamma}(0, y) = f_{\gamma}(x, 0) \equiv 0$ by the definitions of union/intersection over no sets.
2. $f_{\gamma}(1, y) = f_{\gamma}(x, 1) \equiv 0$: the measure of the first set is $\alpha\not\in\{0, 1\}$.
3. Extending the above in one direction, $f_{\gamma}(x, y) \equiv 0$ when $x \leq \frac{1}{\gamma}$ because the union of $x$ of the subintervals has measure bounded above by $\frac{x}{\gamma}$.
4. $\displaystyle\lim_{x^2 + y^2\rightarrow \infty} f(x, y) = 0$.  Because ... it's a pmf and its integral has to be finite.  (Also, from the side of the definition of the distribution ... um, for grad prob theory reasons I currently forget but promise to look up.)

Here's where I get confused.  By definition of pmf, $\sum_{m, n\geq 0} f(m, n) = 1$, so it must be non-zero somewhere.  But ... where?  For the union of the subintervals to have measure 1, it is necessary that the minimum of all left sides of the intervals be 0.  But the probability is zero that that is the case after any finite number of selections, so f(x, y) must seem to be identically zero restricted to a fixed $x$.  What gives?

Comment: Why don't you attempt first to build the pmf of $X_{\gamma}$ and $Y_{\gamma}$ separately ?

Comment: Important: when you say that the $I_k$ are subintervals of length $\gamma$ of $[0,1]$, do you mean that the $I_k$ have no overlap with the **exterior** of interval $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: [Ctd] In a concrete way, if you had to simulate the creation of an $I_k$, how would its endpoints be chosen ?

Comment: Please answer my questions. They could help me to help you...

Comment: @JeanMarie Don't forget that time zones exist: at any given time, roughly one-third of the world is fast asleep.

Comment: @JeanMarie
To answer your questions:
(1) I sort of attempt to do that with $X_{\gamma}$ but run into the issue that ends the post.
(2) That's correct.
(3) Choose the left endpoint $x$ from a uniform distribution on $[0, 1 - \gamma]$, then the interval is $[x, x+\gamma]$.

Comment: About the sleep/non asleep parts of the planet : correct remark.

Comment: About your answer to point (3) : I had well understood, and, as you notice at the end of your question, in this interpretation the probability of having $\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k=[0,1]$ is equal to $0$. This means for me that your interpretation where the $I_k$ are included into $[0,1]$ is not good ; i.e., the $I_k$ should be allowed to have an overlap with the exterior of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'd argue that it makes the question more interesting because of the apparent paradox it creates.  Or does the fact that the probability is zero that $X_{\gamma} = n$ for any given $n$ mean that this not a probability distribution at all?

Comment: That's exactly what you say: you cannot define a discrete random variable $X_{\gamma}$ if its probability is zero everywhere.