# What does this pdf look like?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

This is an extension of [a question I previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569449/what-does-the-probability-mass-function-function-look-like-for-this-parametric-d?noredirect=1#comment9616593_4569449).

Let $\gamma\in(0, 1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be parameters, and let $I_1, I_2, \dots$ be independently and uniformly chosen subintervals of $[0, 1]$ of length $\gamma$ each (isomorphically: let the $I_k$ be independently and uniformly chosen points on the interval $[0, 1 - \gamma]$).

The random variable $x_{\gamma, n}$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$, and $y_{\gamma, n}$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\bigcap_{k=1}^n I_k$.  What is the joint pdf $f_{\gamma, n}(x, y):[0, 1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of $(x_{\gamma, n}, y_{\gamma, n})$?

**Thoughts**
(I will omit subscripts when we can assume that $\gamma$ and $n$ are fixed and there is no risk of ambiguity.)

1. $\big|\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\big|\in \big[\gamma, n\gamma\big]$, so $f(x, y) \equiv 0$ for $x\not\in \big[\gamma, n\gamma\big]$.
2. $\big|\bigcap_{k=1}^n I_k\big|\leq \gamma$, so $f(x, y) \equiv 0$ for $y > \gamma$.
3. When $n = 0$ or $1$, the distributions are very simple:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   f_{\gamma, 0} = \delta_{0, 1}
   \end{align}
   $$ and
   $$
   \begin{align}
   f_{\gamma, 1} = \delta_{\gamma, \gamma}.
   \end{align}
   $$
4. When $n = 2$, $x+y = 2\gamma$ by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.
5. Suppose that $\gamma < \frac{1}{2}$.  Then as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the distribution "converges"  (in a sense I want to make more precise) to $\delta_{1, 0}$.

*Proof of #5*: A necessary condition for $\cup I_n = 1$ is that the minimum of all left endpoints be zero and that the maximum of all right endpoints be 1.  Choosing a small $t > 0$, the probability that the minimum left endpoint is greater than $t$ after $n$ trials is the probability that among $n$ uniformly and ind'ly chosen $t_n$ from $[0, 1 - \gamma]$ none is less than $t$.  This probability is $\Big(\frac{t}{1-\gamma}\Big)^n$, which approaches zero as $n\rightarrow 0$.  A symmetrical argument applies to the right endpoint (though there are independence issues to consider for a fully rigorous treatment).

Comment: I don't understand "isomorphically: let the $I_k$ be independently and uniformly chosen points on the interval $[0,1−γ]$" : this doesn't define an interval...

Comment: @JeanMarie No, but in the context of the problem it is equivalent to choosing a length $\gamma$ closed subinterval.